# Storing JS objects along with prototypes, instance types etc

Tags: javascript, json, object, save, archive

Is it possible to essentially archive the state of a JS object, beyond what would be serialised if you were to produce a JSON string from it?

Thinking in terms of saving state in a game, and loading it back into `window` on a separate occasion.

Comment: What state do you have that wouldn't be included in the JSON string of the object? You need to know the type to do any (de)serialization and the prototype will be inherited then.

Comment: What is your state, if you need store object "constructor" to save it? I think this kind of magic should be avoided. State as plain object + custom store/restore functions seems to be better approach. It is well tested for web applications (see [facebook's flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do it would be to serialize the object, and then recreate it from the serialized data:

```
function AnObject(number, string) {
  this.number = number;
  this.string = string;
  this.add = function(){number++};
}
var initialObject = new AnObject(1, 'a');
var serialized = JSON.stringify(initalObject);
//Gives {"number": 1, "string": "a"}

var parsed = JSON.parse(serialized);
var recreated = new AnObject(parsed.number, parsed.string);
//Is the same as initialObject
```

You can serialize functions if you want:

```
function serializeFunction(f) {
  var string = f.toString();
  return string.substring(string.indexOf('{')+1, string.length - 1);
}
var func = function(){alert(1)};
```

Answer (score 1):

json string can't contain functions, constructors ... I think what you need to do is to define a class where you can find all the methods you need, and then you can instanciate your object from the json data you get. here is a simple example :

```
function Stats (options) {

     this.a = options.a;
     this.b = options.b;
     this.toString = function () { return this.a + ' ' + this.b; };
     this.toJSON = function () { return { a : this.a , b : this.b }; };
     // Methods

     return this;
}
```

in this case , whenever you get your json data, you just need to instanciate your object

```
var stats = new Stats (JSON);
console.log(stats.toString());
```